# Java how to getString from site

Tags: java, jar

Currently I'm trying how to extract this information in the jar file to pass server the information required.

When you trigger this url:

```
http://ipinfo.io/country
```

But the return will be in a 2 variable , so my problem is how to extract since it's not a JSON.

```
   try {
         URL obj = new URL("http://ipinfo.io/country");

         HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

         con.setRequestMethod("GET");
         con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

         con.setDoOutput(true);
         con.setDoInput(true);


         int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

         String joinString = "";
         String decodedString;
         while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
             joinString = joinString + decodedString;
         }
         in.close();
         //-- Logging (joinString) & responseCode
         this.setCountry(new JSONObject(joinString).getString(""));


     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(RegUserRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

     }
```

Comment: You can cast it in List of String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `http://ipinfo.io/country` get request returns a country code as text output.

So why not simply doing :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String countryCode = in.readLine();
```

If it provides directly the data and that you have a single data to retrieve, why do you want to use JSON ?

Comment: We're building a JSON to pass to the server for registration purpose mainly on getter/setter part since we emphasize SOAP API.

Comment: I understand but you can get this data in a raw way and use it when you create our JSON object.

Comment: Raw away as in the apps side decode it or ?? I wish to know about it if it enlighten my current build :)

Comment: When I talk about raw way, I refer to the type of content returned in the response . Here the response is probably returned with a `text/html` or `text/plain` content-type. It is raw/plain text. When a server returns a JSON structure, the content type is generally `application/json`   that returns a response with a specific format : the JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You can print it with:

```
System.out.println(joinString);
```

If you need The GR string is in your joinString as plain text.

Comment: If i want to parse it over , i need to set it by getting the string.. right?

Answer (score 0):

They provide a JSON API that returns JSON and the country code.
But please also consider what they tell you about using their service / API:

> Free usage of our API is limited to 1,000 API requests per day. If you
>   exceed 1,000 requests in a 24 hour period we'll return a 429 HTTP
>   status code to you. If you need to make more requests or custom data,
>   see our paid plans, which all have soft limits.

[image: API returning JSON]

(Taken from https://ipinfo.io/developers/getting-started)

Comment: Currently, we're using that method.. but after 19th December.. the jar returns empty countrycode.. That's why i need to find alternative.